# SQL - how to display employees that has sum less than 5000

Tags: sql, sql-server, rdbms

I have encountered a problem here. in the total_trans_amount column, How do I check the sum of total_trans_amount for each employee and display those employee which has less than 5000 in total. Based on the image below, P0947 should have a total of 5700. I want to remove the three row data that consist of P0947 because it exceeds 5700. Please refer to my current SQL query and image below.

```
SELECT DISTINCT b
    ,SUM(trans_amount2) AS [total_trans_amount]
    ,adjust_amount
    ,trans_amount2
    ,transaction_order
    ,reimname_en
    ,currency_code
    ,remark
    ,disease
FROM temp_reim_used
WHERE company_code = 'pdc'
    AND reim_code = 'CLNC_NPL'
    AND a = a
    AND b = b
    AND trans_amount != 0
    AND reimbalance_id = reimbalance_id
    AND (
        (created_date >= {d '2017-01-01' }
            AND created_date <= {d '2017-09-23' })
        )
GROUP BY b
    ,reim_code
    ,adjust_amount
    ,trans_amount2
    ,transaction_order
    ,reimname_en
    ,currency_code
    ,remark
    ,disease
HAVING SUM(trans_amount2) > - 6000
ORDER BY b ASC
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add extra filter like this:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
   SELECT b,
     SUM(trans_amount2) as [total_trans_amount]
   FROM temp_reim_used
  where company_code = 'pdc' AND reim_code = 'CLNC_NPL'
  AND a = a AND b = b
  AND trans_amount != 0  AND reimbalance_id = reimbalance_id
  AND ((created_date >= {d '2017-01-01'} AND created_date <= {d '2017-09-23'})) 
   GROUP BY b
)
SELECT 
  b,
  SUM(trans_amount2) as [total_trans_amount], 
  adjust_amount,trans_amount2,transaction_order,
  reimname_en , currency_code, remark, disease
from temp_reim_used
where company_code = 'pdc' AND reim_code = 'CLNC_NPL'
  AND a = a AND b = b
  AND trans_amount != 0  AND reimbalance_id = reimbalance_id
  AND ((created_date >= {d '2017-01-01'} AND created_date <= {d '2017-09-23'})) 
  AND b IN (SELECT b FROM CTE WHERE total_trans_amount >= -5000)
GROUP BY b,reim_code, adjust_amount,trans_amount2,transaction_order, 
reimname_en, currency_code, remark, disease 
having SUM(trans_amount2) >-6000 
order by b asc
```

Things to note here:

- The `CTE` will give you the total amount for each `b`. So these three rows will give you the 5700.
- The condition `AND b IN (SELECT b FROM CTE WHERE total_trans_amount >= -5000)` will give you only those rows that less than `-5000`.
- No need for `DISTINCT` with `GROUP BY` the way you did.

Answer (score 0):

well try this:

```
WITH subSource
AS (
    /* your query here */
    )
    ,subSource2 AS (
    SELECT b
        ,total_trans_amount
        ,adjust_amount
        ,trans_amount2
        ,transaction_order
        ,reimname_en
        ,currency_code
        ,remark
        ,disease
        ,sum(total_trans_amount) OVER (PARTITION BY b /*maybe more?*/) AS tempTotal
    FROM subSource
    )
SELECT b
    ,total_trans_amount
    ,adjust_amount
    ,trans_amount2
    ,transaction_order
    ,reimname_en
    ,currency_code
    ,remark
    ,disease
FROM subSource2
WHERE tempTotal <= 5000 /* or just '<' ? */
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you wrote too many "things" in your query.
Can you see if this is right for you?

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT b,
        adjust_amount,
        trans_amount,
        SUM(trans_amount) OVER (PARTITION BY b) AS TOTAL_TRANS_AMOUNT
        transaction_order,
        reimname_en, 
        currency_code, 
        remark, 
        disease
    from temp_reim_used
    where company_code = 'pdc' 
        AND reim_code = 'CLNC_NPL'
        AND trans_amount != 0  
        AND reimbalance_id = reimbalance_id
        AND created_date >= {d '2017-01-01'} AND created_date <= {d '2017-09-23'}
    ) X
WHERE   TOTAL_TRANS_AMOUNT>-5000
ORDER BY b
```